# faster way to handle time string with python

Tags: python

I have many log files with the format like:

```
2012-09-12 23:12:00 other logs here
```

and i need to extract the time string and compare the time delta between two log records.
I did that with this:

```
for line in log:
    l = line.strip().split()
    timelist = [int(n) for n in re.split("[- :]", l[0]+' ' + l[1])]
    #now the timelist looks like [2012,9,12,23,12,0]
```

Then when i got two records

```
d1 = datetime.datetime(timelist1[0], timelist1[1], timelist1[2], timelist1[3], timelist1[4], timelist1[5])
d2 = datetime.datetime(timelist2[0], timelist2[1], timelist2[2], timelist2[3], timelist2[4], timelist2[5])
delta = (d2-d1).seconds
```

The problem is it runs slowly,is there anyway to improve the performance?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your profile for your "runs slowly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of the regex and use `map`:

```
date_time = datetime.datetime

for line in log:
    date, time = line.strip().split(' ', 2)[:2]

    timelist = map(int, date.split('-') + time.split(':'))
    d = date_time(*timelist)
```

- I *think* `.split(' ', 2)` will be faster than just `.split()` because it only splits up to two times and only on spaces, not on any whitespace.
- `map(int, l)` is faster than `[int(x) for x in l]` the last time I checked.
- If you can, get rid of `.strip()`.

Comment: This is approximately 3x faster than the standard `datetime.strptime` for me.  Another *micro* optimization is to assign a new (local) name to `datetime.datetime`.  So, you could do `date_time = datetime.datetime`, and then use `date_time`.  This will save you a dictionary lookup which is usually trivial, but over many many accesses can be noticable.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that the local variable trick isn't one which I think is looked upon extremely favorably by the community (most of the time, the optimization is definitely not worth it).  I think it should only be used when it gives a measurable speedup, and even then, it's probably nice to leave a comment saying that the speedup is actually worth it in a particular case.

Comment: @mgilson why stop at renaming `datetime.datetime`? A `strptime = lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x, common_format)` would be worth a try. But then, without actual time tests, tough to know

Answer (score 1):

You could do it entirely with regular expressions, which might be faster.

```
find_time = re.compile("^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})")

for line in log:
    timelist = find_time.match(line)
    if timelist:
        d = datetime.datetime(*map(int, timelist.groups()))
```

Comment: I think you'd have to do `map(int, find_time.findall(line))`, as `datetime.datetime()` only accepts integer arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try without regexp, using the optional argument of `split`

```
(date, time, log) = line.split(" ", 2)
timerecord = datetime.datetime.strptime(date+" "+time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

and then it'd be a matter of computing your `timedeltas` between consecutive `timerecord`s