# what's the fastest way of converting a string time stamp into epoch time with python?

Tags: python

I need to do lots of conversation from string time stamp like '2012-09-08 12:23:33' into a seconds which is based on epoch time.Then i need to get time gap between two timestamp.I tried two different ways:

```
date1 = '2012-09-08'
time2 = '12:23:33'
timelist1 = map(int, date1.split('-') + time1.split(':'))

date2 = '2012-09-08'
time2 = '12:23:33'
timelist2 = map(int, date2.split('-') + time2.split(':'))
delta = datetime.datetime(*timelist2) - datetime.datetime(*timelist1)
print delta.seconds
```

The second way is:

```
date1 = '2012-09-08'
time1 = '12:23:33'
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1 + ' ' + time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
seconds1 = time.mktime(d1.timetuple())
....
seconds2 = time.mktime(d2.timetuple())
print seconds2-deconds1
```

However these two ways are not fast enough because I have almost 100 millions actions to do.Any suggestion?

Comment: If you are parsing logs or other data sorted by time, then i suggest you to cache the result of `mktime(strptime())`. If you have more than 10 lines per minutes, caching everything but the seconds can be really effective. Alternatively, you could cache only the date. `mktime` and `strptime` function are just so damn slow.

Comment: Thanks,yeah,I'v already do the cache,while i post the codes here without caching in case of misunderstanding.

Comment: Follow up of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399162/faster-way-to-handle-time-string-with-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be much better off using the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), then subtract the two results:

```
import datetime

date1, time1 = '2012-09-08', '12:23:33'
date2, time2 = '2012-09-08', '12:23:33'

dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1 + ' ' + time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2 + ' ' + time2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print (dt1 - dt2).total_seconds()
```

Note that `datetime.timedelta.seconds` gives you just the *remainder* in seconds, there is also a `.days` attribute. Use [`.total_seconds()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) instead, it's much more convenient and saves you having to take the `.days` value into account.

Using the `datetime.datetime.strptime()` method, plus `timedelta` methods, is keeping the majority of the work in C code and should be faster.

Note that neither method is very fast because of the parsing step. Time tests:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def parse_datetime():
...     date1, time1 = '2012-09-08', '12:23:33'
...     date2, time2 = '2012-09-08', '12:23:33'
...     dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date1 + ' ' + time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
...     dt2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2 + ' ' + time2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
...     (dt1 - dt2).total_seconds()
... 
>>> def parse_time():
...     d1 = time.strptime(date1 + ' ' + time1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
...     d2 = time.strptime(date2 + ' ' + time2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
...     seconds1 = time.mktime(d1)
...     seconds2 = time.mktime(d2)
...     seconds1 - seconds2
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('test()', 'from __main__ import parse_datetime as test', number=10000)
0.6590030193328857
>>> timeit.timeit('test()', 'from __main__ import parse_time as test', number=10000)
0.7742340564727783
```

where the second method just uses the `time.strptime()` function (which outputs a timetuple directly).

There are no faster avenues to parsing a date-time string that I am aware of though.